# Resources for translating common programming terms for UI into other languages

Tags: translation, spoken-language

I'm not even sure this is entirely programming related...but here goes:

I need to translate some forms into different languages, specifically Spanish and French. Obviously, it would be good if I knew these other languages fluently, but I don't. Besides doing a Google translate, babel fish, etc. are there any resources which can assist in this? Mainly I am trying to find out what the translation of OK and Cancel are.

Moreover, I looked to find some programs which have the UI written in these other languages and all I could find were language learning programs.

How do other programmers handle doing this?

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But use **Google translate**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Take a look at the Pootle Terminology project:

http://pootle.locamotion.org/projects/terminology/

and Microsoft's UI translations:

http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Translations.aspx

Both provide translations for common UI terminology in a range of languages.

Comment: Definitely the Spanish PO file taught me a bunch of programming words that I only knew in English and I speak Spanish fluently. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: Both those links no longer exist

Comment: An alternative MicroSoft resource can now be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it right, it seems like you need to hire a person to translate for you.  Preferably a native speaker.  I'm sure you can find some services through a quick google search.

Answer (score 4):

The best resource for this is probably a translator who speaks the language in question fluently and has experience translating user interfaces.

Here's just one example of a company that provides this service:

http://www.ricintl.com/software-localization-services.htm

Comment: Leads to a dead, not secure empty page

Answer (score 1):

For spanish is ok to user: "Ok and "Cancelar"

Comment: Interesting, I actually thought that it was a command and needed to translate "Cancel" to "Cancele" instead of the infinitive.

Comment: Yeah, the same goes for Portuguese. Always use the infinitive (Abrir, Sair, Excluir).